# can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Tags: python

I need help unscrambling this code. I am only allowed to use these specific lines of code, but I need to 'unscramble' it to make it work. To me, this code looks good but I don't seem to get it to work so I would like to find out why this is the case.

The assignment that I am trying to solve is as follows:

> Read in the file using the csv reader and build a dictionary with the tree species as the key and a count of the number of times the tree appears. Use the "in" operator to see if a tree has been added, and if not set it to 1.
> Print the dictionary with the counts at the end.

My code is as follows:

```
from BrowserFile import open as _
import csv
with open("treeinventory.csv", "r", newline='') as f:
    count = {}
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for yard in reader:
        for tree in yard:
            if tree in count:
                count[tree] = 1
            else: 
                count[tree] = count[tree] + 1
print(count)
```

I would love if someone can help me and also explain why this code is not able to work as it is, i am trying to learn and this would be very helpful!

thank you!

Comment: "if a tree has been added, and **if not** set it to 1. "

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead? Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You should choose a better title for your question

Comment: `from BrowserFile import open` what is this import for ? I mean, `open` should already be accessible in global scope and you don't need to import it from some random package

Comment: It is very suspect to overwrite the default `open` with some other imported `open` Use a different name for it!

Comment: inspect what does the `if ..: ... else...` statement in the `for tree in yard` loop.

Comment: You just have your `if` and `else` backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we don't solve "homework" problems on SO.  You should also try to ask specific questions.  Also put better titles on your questions.  And, as such, I always like to post [This](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) to help new question askers out.

Since I'm here: The answer to your assignment is that line 9 and line 11 are swapped.

This is because the logic seems to set that dict `count` with the key `tree` is being set to `1` if the key is in the dict, and add `1` to the value stored at `count[tree]` if it's *not* in the dict.  This will result in a KeyError exception to be thrown when the value is accessed to do this addition in the statement `count[tree] + 1`, because, there is no value there yet.

Of course, without the input file, I can't actually run the code to verify it, so please try this out for yourself and update your question with specific issues if any come up.